# Batch raster calculator with ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10.6

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, arcgis-10.6

I have 30 images of Sentinel-2 data.

How can I calculate NDVI in batch?

I tried to solve the problem with ModelBuilder, but there can only be 1 iteration tool in the model. I additionally created a submodel, but each raster from the submodel is iterated over with all from the main one.
[image: Text]

And the images don't match. And after first iteration 
Float((Raster(r"С:\Input\S2B_MSIL2A_PCL\ **PCL** _B08_10m.jp2") - Raster(r"C:\Input\S2A_MSIL2A_SXT\ **SXT** _B04_10m.jp2")) / (Raster(r"С:\Input\S2B_MSIL2A_PCL\ **PCL** _B08_10m.jp2") + Raster(r"C:\Input\S2A_MSIL2A_SXT\ **SXT** _B04_10m.jp2")))<br/

**I will add the question**
<br/Here I'v got 15 subfolders with sentinel data - C:\Input\S2*\S2A*\GRANULE\L2A*\IMG_DATA\R10m\bandX.jp2

I want to understand how it's possible to process all rasters using python.
For example, I put 4 Bands (Band4 x2 and Band8 x2) to C:\Input and use this code

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"<C:\Input>" #define the workspace (your input path)

raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters(("*B04_10m"))
for raster in raster_list:
print("YEAH!")
rasRed = Raster(raster)
rasNIR = Raster(raster.replace('B04','B08')) #corresponding NIR band
outraster = float((rasNIR-rasRed)/(rasNIR+rasRed))        
outraster.save(raster.replace('B04','NDVI'))#change the input name to NDVI
```

There is an error in line 4, 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

If I use these two codes - no error and no result.

```
import glob
 
 for raster in glob.glob(r"C:\Input\S2*\*B04_10m.jp2"):
     print(raster)
     rasRed = Raster(raster)
     rasNIR = Raster(raster.replace('B04','B08'))
     outRaster = float(rasNIR-rasRed)/float(rasNIR+rasRed)
     outraster.save(raster.replace('B04','NDVI'))
```

```
import glob
 
 for raster in glob.glob(r"C:\Sentinel_input\S2*\S2*\GRANULE\L2*\IMG*\R10*\*B04_10m.jp2"):
     print(raster)
     rasRed = Raster('raster')
     rasNIR = Raster(raster.replace('B04','B08'))
     outRaster = float(rasNIR-rasRed)/float(rasNIR+rasRed)
     outraster.save(raster.replace('B04','NDVI'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

workaround for double iteration quickly becomes very complex in Model Builder. Here is a small Python script that you could run directly in the ArcGIS Python command prompts:

```
import glob
from arcpy.sa import *

for raster in glob.glob(r"С:\Input\S2*\*B04_10m.jp2"):
    print(raster) #check that you find the rasters
    rasRed = Raster(raster)
    rasNIR = Raster(raster.replace('B04','B08')) #corresponding NIR band
    outraster = Float(rasNIR-rasRed)/(rasNIR+rasRed)        
    outraster.save(raster.replace('B04','NDVI')#change the input name to NDVI, store in the <location_path> location
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have antoher problem - invalid syntax (line 6) appears when running code. Do I need to specify the path to each folder?

Comment: sorry, I did not test my code. Could you try again with the update ?

Comment: still an error in line 6

Comment: @BERA thank you! There is no more error. But there is no result too. To be honest, I don't know how the process should look like. The code runs for a few seconds and that's all. Target folder is empty

Comment: Thank you all for your time! Now the error is File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Does this mean that the code does not search for rasters through subfolders?

Comment: yes, it only looks for rasters in a given folder. if you have different subfolder it is better to use glob.

Comment: note that, at this stage, the NDVI file will be written in each folder.

Comment: There is still no result. My path to the subfolder with sentinel data is - C:\Input\S2B*\S2B*\GRANULE\L2*\IMG_DATA\R10m\*_1.tif, C:\Input\S2B*\S2B*\GRANULE\L2*\IMG_DATA\R10m\*_2.tif. Maybe an error in the data path?

Comment: first you need to check if there is something in the list. If so you should have the name of the raster that prints, and the problem is my code. If not, it is a problem with the path. Note that it is done for single band rasters.

Comment: The error was in the path and I fixed it. But now the error is on line 6 `rasRed = Raster (raster)` - 'Raster' is not defined. How can I fix it?

Comment: try with from arcpy.sa import *

Comment: That's it! But now another error on line 8 - float() argument must be a string or a number `outRaster = float(rasNIR-rasRed)/float(rasNIR+rasRed)`. If I remove the float, the code runs, makes 1 calculation and reports - line 9 Output raster format UNKNOWN is unsupported. `outraster.save(raster.replace('B04','NDVI')`

Comment: it should be Float, not float, sorry about the typo. If you don't use Float, your output will be integer (-1 0 or 1) which will not help you . What does a print of raster.replace('B04','NDVI') give you? there seems to be a problem in the name but now I've tested my code and I don't have errors.

Comment: Replacing float with float helped. But again problem with format. The result is stored in temporary memory, it has a strange AFR format. Is it possible to specify an output folder and format for the output data? Could the problem be in the input .jp2 format?

Comment: yes, jp2 could be an issue. try replacing jp2 with tif raster.replace('B04','NDVI').replace("jp2","tif")

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your time! I couldn't have done it without you. Could you help me onemore time? How can I set output folder? When I try this `outraster.save(r"<C:\Output>"+raster.replace('B04','NDVI').replace("jp2","tif"))` I get an error.

Comment: raster is the full path. you can split it to take only the file name filename = raster.split("\")[-1] , then concatenate the updated filename with the output dir. note that <> meant that you had to fill with your value, but it must'nt remain r"C:\Output\" + filename.replace.... make use of print() to check that it works. More robust is to use import os  then  os.path.basename(raster)